# Why do I need to enable razor runtime compile? Am I taking crazy pills?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

As far as I know I've always been able to update cshtml files and immediately see changes (upon refreshing browser) without having to stop my project.

But as I am creating a new project I see this new option to enable this feature and I'm wondering what it is because, after all, I've always been able to do this. But as far as I can tell it does exactly what it says... as if I wasn't able to do this in the past?

But I also notice now that when I make a change to a razor page, it takes a looot longer to see the update as Visual Studio recompiles the project.

What... is... going... on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I know I've always been able to update cshtml files and
> immediately see changes (upon refreshing browser) without having to
> stop my project.

Yes.Before asp.net core 3.0,you could do it by default.After asp.net core 3.0,you could install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` NuGet package to enable runtime compilation.

1.Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` NuGet package.

2.Update the project's `Startup.ConfigureServices` method to include a call to `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation`:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#enable-runtime-compilation-in-an-existing-project

**Update:**

From asp.net core 3.1,you could select the **Enable Razor runtime compilation** checkbox in the **Create a new ASP.NET Core web application** dialog:

[image]

Comment: Okay, so I did that already and it works but my problem is that now every time I make a tiny change to something that's not even code related it has to needlessly recompile. The extra time it takes to do this adds up VERY quickly when I'm testing out css style changes. There is no reason for this when there are no code changes. Does this mean that they have actually made it worse than it was before?

Comment: This is by design,and if you want to know the reason why caused that,I think you need ask in github,because we are not vs or asp.net core designer.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if I was just missing something because it seems pretty insane that they would introduce a new "feature" that really ruins (performance-wise) an already existing feature.

Comment: I appreciate it, though I figured this out on my own. My problem is that I didn't used to have to wait for the application to recompile every time I made a cshtml change. Now I do. It's a huge time waster.

Comment: This does not work anymore (April 2021). You have to hit refresh button on browser. Hot reload does not work!